# Query that counts the comments for each panelist

Tags: sql, join

I have four tables with the following structure:

1. `panelists` (`panelist_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, etc.)
2. `projects` (`project_id`, `title`, `created_date`, etc.)
3. `panelists_on_projects` (`pp_id`, `panelist_id`, `project_id`, etc.)
4. `comments` (`comment_id`, `panelist_id`, `project_id`, etc.)

Imagine I have four panelists on the same project ("x"), but only 3 of the panelists have left a comment.  I am trying to figure out a query that counts the comments for each panelist and returns a zero for the panelist attached to project x, but who has not left a comment.

I tried using the following:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(comment_id)
from panelists
INNER JOIN comments USING (panelist_id)
WHERE project = x
```

But I only get results for the 3 panelists who have actually left a comment. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please always mention which DB you're using. SQL varies widely between them; for instance, SQL Server has many possibilities not available in MySQL (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

The `outer join` is the key part, also I think you forgot about the project in the comments join. When you count by a specific column, null values will not be counted.

```
select
    pj.project_id,
    p.panelist_id,
    p.firstname,
    p.lastname,
    totalcomments = count(c.comment_id)
from
    project pj
    inner join panelists_on_projects pop on pop.project_id = pj.project_id
    inner join panelist p on p.panelist_id = pop.panelist_id
    left outer join comments c on
        c.panelist_id = p.panelist_id
        and c.project_id = pj.project_id
where
    pj.title = 'X'
group by
    pj.project_id,
    p.panelist_id,
    p.firstname,
    p.lastname
```

Comment: The second condition on the comments join isn't necessary as you will already be limited to one project by the title refinement in the where clause.

Comment: @tgandrews Not true. The where clause only selects the correct row in the project table, it does not filter the comments in any way without the second join condition. The asker doesn't want comments for other projects to be counted.

Comment: @Aleksi - Yes you are right. I have changed by answer to be as correct as yours.

Comment: @dotjoe Shouldn't it be `count(c.comment_id) AS totalcomments` instead of `totalcomments = count(c.comment_id)`?

Comment: You guys are seriously awesome.  I would have NEVER figured that out by myself.  NEVER.  To the StackOverflow community - YOU RULE!

Comment: @Aleksi you can do either way in tsql :) I prefer the `=` to keep all the column names in line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. Although if you know the project_id you can go straight to the panelists_on_projects table.

```
select
    pan.first_name
    , pan.last_name
    , count(com.comment_id)
from
    projects proj
    inner join panelists_on_project pop
        on proj.panelist_id = pop.panelist_id
    inner join panelist pan
        on pop.panelist_id = pan.panelist_id
    left outer join comments com
        on pan.panelist_id = com.panelist_id
        and com.project_id = proj.project_id
where
    proj.title = 'x'
group by
    pan.first_name
    , pan.last_name
```

Without the 2nd condition `and com.project_id = proj.project_id` on the comments join this would be the count of the total number of comments for all projects of the panelists that were on project 'x'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.first_name, P.last_name, COUNT(C.comment_id)

FROM panelists as P

LEFT JOIN panelists_on_projects AS PP ON PP.panelist_id = P.panelist_id

LEFT JOIN projects AS PR PN PP.project_id = PR.project_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN comments As C ON C.panelist_id = P.panelist_id AND C.project_id = PR.project_id

WHERE PR.title = "x"
```